# Resize img to window size keeping aspect ratio / no overflow on height or width

Tags: css, image, html, resize, fluid

I realise this question has been asked multiple times in differently worded titles and options, but i have yet to find something that works for me.

Im trying to have an img fill most of the screen (keeping its aspect ratio) without overflowing the edges. (Basically what the firefox browser accomplishes when viewing an image)

Most that i've tried either works in only one direction ie. width will resize but will end up overflowing the height and the same for the other way, either with CSS or JScript. Also playing a factor in my trouble is that i want to aplly this to both portrait and landscape images (More or less any image i have on the site)

This seems like it should work using pure CSS but doesnt (im not completely knowledgeable in all CSS though):

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XCfQg/4/)

```
body, html {
    margin:auto;
    padding:6px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;

}
img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

There are a hand full of other scripts as well, but this post is getting a bit long.

Could anyone help me out containing my images within the screen, with either JQuery or CSS (within or without a DIV)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Man i got mixed up trying to make that link, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

**MY ANSWER:**

I ended up just wrapping the image in a div and setting the div dimensions in CSS:

[PURE CSS Resize](http://jsfiddle.net/jcAGj/)

Unfortunately this method may look quite horrible in older browsers but it has atleast got me out of a pickle and its a tiny piece of styling.

Hopefully i can find some jQuery alternative soon.

```
body, html {
    width:98%;
    height:98%;
}
.outer {
  position:fixed !important;
  position:absolute;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  top:10px;
  right:0;
  bottom:10px;
  left:0;
}
img {
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;    
padding:4px;
background-color:#fff;
}

----
<div class="outer">
<img src="whatever.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this jQuery plugin: **[TailorFit](https://github.com/rtheunissen/tailorfit)**
and check out the **[demo](http://dev.fhmp.net/tailorfit/demo/)**.

You can play around with various options in the demo to figure out if this could work for you. The browser support is extreme because it only uses jQuery and relative positioning.

Full disclosure - I'm the author of the plugin.

Comment: That, my friend, is freaking nice. Ill have to book mark your page for future reference.

Comment: It was my first plugin and I haven't touched it in a very long time. Might revive and improve it soon if I know that people are using it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Now define your `html, body height 100%;`

as like this

```
body, html {
     height:100%;
}
```